# Setting Security Rules w/o Dashboard

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way for the owner of a Firebase database to set the security rules via the browser or curl or some other means than the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers given on the google group for firebase:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/firebase-talk/LwSddjJclxY
One is a REST approach, the other uses a configuration file, firebase.json.